# Alarm gets instantly fired on a Raspberry RP2040

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi, c, rp2040

I'm writing a program to manage the velocity of a motor that is remotely controlled.

For security reasons, I want to stop the motor after one second after it receives a command if it doesn't receive another.

I have a "motor" struct:

```c
motor mt = {
    .m_pwm_pin=M_PWM,
    .timeout=1000,
    .freq=50.0,
    .cycle_time=0.000000008,
    .divider=256.0,
    .forward_period=2.0,
    .neutral_period=1.5,
    .backward_period=1.0,
    .motor_kv=2150 
};
```

This is the code I wrote:

```c
int64_t cb_stop_motor(long id, void *mot) {
    motor *m = mot;
    stop_motor(m);
    return 0;
}

int stop_motor(motor *m) {
    gpio_put(16, 1);
    pwm_set_chan_level(m->slice, PWM_CHAN_B, getDuty(m->neutral_period));
    return 0;
}

int move_motor(motor *m, int rpm) {
    double period_per_rpm;
    double m_period;

    if (rpm == 0) {
        stop_motor(m);
    }
    else if (rpm < 0) {
        period_per_rpm = (m->neutral_period - m->backward_period) / ((double) m->motor_kv);
        m_period = m->neutral_period - (period_per_rpm * (double) rpm * -1.0);
    }
    else if (rpm > 0) {
        period_per_rpm = (m->forward_period - m->neutral_period) / ((double) m->motor_kv);
        m_period = m->neutral_period + (period_per_rpm * (double) rpm);
    }

    pwm_set_chan_level(m->slice, PWM_CHAN_B, getDuty(m_period));
    
    cancel_alarm(m->alarm_id);

    m->alarm_id = add_alarm_in_ms(m->timeout, cb_stop_motor, m, true);
}
```

The problem is that immediatly after the `move_motor` command the alarm is fired. I know that becouse I checked with an oscilloscope. The period goes to 1.72 ms for an instant and then goes back to 1.5 ms.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Why don't you evaluate any return codes? It could give you an indication what's going wrong.

Comment: Hi Seir, what codes do you think I should evaluate?

Comment: You should evaluate all return codes. Even if you _know_ their value, you should at least verify it using an assertion. For instance [add_alarm_in_ms()](https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/group__alarm.html#ga8bb045ab597f773d7d5fdfea5db94f69) returns -1 if there were no alarm slots available, and 0 if the alarm time passed before or during the call AND there is no active alarm to return the id of.

Comment: Also take note of the `fire_if_past` argument. I haven't used this API myself, so I can't dig any further.

Comment: How often are you calling `move_motor`?

Comment: I remember that I had to use an explicit alarm pool otherwise the alarm would interfere with `sleep`, but your application may differ.

Comment: If resetting the chip puts the motor in a safe mode, consider using the hardware watchdog instead of an alarm.

Comment: Finally, do you have the same issue if you `add_alarm_at` instead and give an `absolute_time_t` deadline?

Comment: "I want to stop the motor after one second after it receives a command if it doesn't receive another." - this is a great idea and should be implemented on many things, continue doing good work like this.

Answer (score 1):

Just found what was missing.
I tried to set `fire_if_past` to false and evaluate the return codes, still nothing.

Seems like the time in milliseconds should be specified with an added zero. By setting timeout=10000 I get a 1s timeout as wanted.

Comment: Is it possible that your hardware clock ([clock_configure](https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/group__hardware__clocks.html#ga90f15783df4e2cb041971a197b2119b1)) is configured with the wrong frequency?

Comment: The only "edit" at the clock is done for the pwm by using ```pwm_set_clkdiv(m->slice, m->divider);``` with a divider of 256. Could that be a problem? Seems weird to me.

Comment: Without knowing the details, it's very unlikely that the alarm is tied to the PWM module.